# Custom Tag Nest For PDF Accessibility

Tags: pdf, accessibility, nested-lists, acrobat, tagging

Is it possible to create a nested tag tree as a group rather than individually create each tag in Adobe Acrobat when tagging a PDF document for accessibility? It doesn't seem to be a native function of Acrobat.

Say there is a list that needs to be tagged manually; I would have to create the 
list tag, L and then any list item tag, LI (and each list items’ label and list body tags) after.

Is there a way to auto-populate the nest so if I create a new list tag, it would already have a list item tag nested inside it? And/or for each list item tag created, the label and item body tags are automatically nested inside the list item tag?

Comment: What tool are you using to author the document in the first place? Many tools like Microsoft Office create accessible PDF automatically as long as you don't print to PDF and use the Acrobat toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Acrobat as your tagging tool, then your best chance is to hopefully have the tags created correctly at the time of conversion from your source document (e.g. MS Word).

I use CommonLook PDF, and while it is expensive, it will do what you're describing. It doesn't work especially well on multi-level lists (they require some manual correction), but it is infinitely faster than manually tagging in Acrobat.